# iPhone plist file versions... Adding keys sometimes does not work

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, plist, target

I created an iPhone project using the Core Data template. Now when I try to change my plist file to "Status bar is initially hidden = YES" I can't find that key in my options. Instead I find a lot of keys that are relevant to Core Data, keys that I've never seen before.

Anyway, I add the key "Status bar is initially hidden" myself and set it to a Boolean value and then tick. But just doesn't work. The status bar is there.

Are there many versions or types of property list files for the iPhone? What do the available keys depend on? And finally, how can I achieve what I want? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the key "UIStatusBarHidden" and set it to true. That's the name that is used internally in the plist when "Status bar is initially hidden" is set.

Comment: Yes, this worked. But why does this happen? Is there a way to tell Xcode to treat my plist files differently?

Comment: Using the raw key instead of the human-readable long version works because it's the way XCode stores it in the plist file. Actually, you can change the display mode to show raw keys for all the entries in the plist file by Ctrl-clicking one key and checking "Show raw keys/values".

About how to change which key values are present by default in the drop-down list, I don't have an answer.

You can find further information on plist files in the Information Property List Key Reference document: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/